# Enable/Disable ASP.NET control with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm building a page to upload an Excel file on the server for an import operation. So a found a javascript to check the file selected file extension void other file types. Now I'm trying to enable the upload ASP.NET button but javascript returns the error `document.getElementById(...)` is null.

Here the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" defer="defer">
    function enableControl() {
        document.getElementById('button').disable = false;
    }

    function disableControl() {
        document.getElementById('button').disable = true;
    }

    function checkExcelFileUpload(elem) {
        var filePath = elem.value;
        if (filePath.indexOf('.') == -1)
            return false;
        var validExtensions = new Array();
        var ext = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
        //Add valid extentions in this array
        validExtensions[0] = 'xls';
        //validExtensions[1] = 'pdf';
        for (var i = 0; i < validExtensions.length; i++) {
            if (ext == validExtensions[i])
                return true;
        }
        elem.value = '';
        alert('Sono ammessi solo file di Excel 97-2003');
        return false;
    }
</script>
<asp:FileUpload ID="fileupload" runat="server" size="50" onchange="javascript:try{if(checkExcelFileUpload(this) == true){enableControl();}else{disableControl();}}catch(err){alert(err);};" />
<asp:Button ID="button" runat="server" Text="Upload" Enabled="False" />
```

I serached on internet and I found other syntax for `getElementById` but I still have this problem.
Can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: your button is server side so the ID is changed when it is rendered. try removing runat="server" tag. You may also need to change other Tags like "Text, Enabled" etc. Basically you are now creating a HTML button and not ASP.Net button.

Answer (score 6):

**Option 1**
Since your button is a server side control, the rendered ID will be different that what you have specified. Use the following code to generate the `ctl$body$button` (something along these lines depending on the nesting of your controls).

```
document.getElementById('<%= button.ClientID %>')
```

**Option 2**
If you are using ASP.NET 4, you can use the `Static` client ID mode.

`<asp:Button ID="button" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Upload" Enabled="False" />`

See http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Comment: Do you see any errors on the console? You may be dealing with other issues that are blocking you.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
document.getElementById('button').disable = false;
```

You'll probably want:

```
document.getElementById('<%= this.button.ClientID %>').disabled = false;
```

Comment: You need to use .disabled, not .disable